# Recursive expression in typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, logic

Let's say I want to make a set of logic rules stored in an object :

```js
const rule1 : Rule = {
  ">" : [3,2]
}; // Which represents : 3>2

const rule2 : Rule = {
  "and" : [
    { ">" : [3,1] },
    { "<" : [1,3] }
  ]
}; // Which represents : (3>1) && (1<3)
```

I have written my types as such :

```js
type Operand = number | string | Rule

type Operator =
  "var" |
  "===" |
  "!==" |
  "<="  |
  "<"   |
  ">="  |
  ">"   |
  "or"  |
  "and" ;

interface Rule extends Record<Operator, [Operand, Operand]> { }
```

But I get the following error `Type '{ ">": [number, number]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<Operator, [Operand, Operand]>': var, "===", "!==", "<=", and 4 more.`

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simpler answer than the one provided by @Titian that doesn't require any Typescript black magic (distributive property of conditional types)

```js
type Operators = "var" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "===" | "!==" | "and" | "or";
type Operand = number | string | Rule;
type Operands = [Operand, Operand?];

type Rule = {
  [key in Operators]?: Operands; // note the '?' that makes every properties of Rule not required
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`interface Rule extends Record<Operator, [Operand, Operand]> { }` will name all the operators required on any given rule.

You can extend `Partial<Record<Operator, [Operand, Operand]>>` and make them all optional. This would mean that a rule can specify multiple operators, which might not be what you want:

```
interface Rule extends Partial<Record<Operator, [Operand, Operand]>> { }
const rule1 : Rule = {
  ">" : [3, 2],
  "<" : [3, 2]
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgVwDYFMCMMBcMBKyUwC8MA3gFAwwBEAfFVjANoDMANDAEwC6rF1APPWwt23MgF8A3GTKhIsRKg4M8qIqT5UAhmAAmQpn0olqdBiLRcY43pWMCDjNK2ZXxfLhMkwZUAJ4ADgQA8kFwOrrqYAgAtgBGKHAwAD4w0HAAlmAA5im4+L6BIWFaUCBJhJoAblpw9MmahE31mgCEzSma-IT0nZRUgnYN-TQ9lMOmvX3U5b0T2nr00mRZUIkAZlrABKoEKAAea3oQMAAKtVAZWkj8OCigcLr8oYml5eyML+F67F8RXDQaKRrEA)

You could also not use an interface, but instead generate a union where each object type has one operator required:

```
type Rule<T extends Operator = Operator> =  T extends T ? Record<T, [Operand, Operand]> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Operator, T>, undefined>>: never;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgVwDYFMCMMBcMBKyUwC8MA3gFAwwBEAfFVjANoDMANDAEwC6rF1APPWwt23MgF8A3DAD0MmAHUAFgEtgS+CgAOcFBBRgoEBsxocyZUJFiJUHBnlRFSfKgEMwAEyFM+lEtR0DCJoXDDivJT+Aj6MaKzMYeJ8XBLSFlAAnloEAPI5cB6ezmAIALYARihwMAA+MNBwKmAA5nW4+BnZeQVuUCA1hK4Abm5w9LWuhNMTrgCEM3Wu-IT0S5RUglGTGzSrlDuBa+vUA2uH7l70kl05Haj8ACowKAAeUAaexvnVfQPOP0K-TgNGcMGebw+XmMzwA-LgUKA4J4nuxGICiuwMV4uKCAGQwAAKYygKjcSH4OERAxRAFFXsAkAhPCh+BjgexHjR2AgvCgAGbNFCeGg0bBgFDDaqSIA)

With this second solution `Rule` basically generates a union of types using the [distributive property of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Basically we get:

```
Rule = Record<"var", [Operand, Operand]> | Record<"===", [Operand, Operand]> | Record<"!==", [Operand, Operand]> | ... 5 more ... | Record<...>
```

This means that each constituent of the union has exactly one required property. To also ensure other don't have other properties (unions can allow members from other constituents), we also add to each object type all the other properties but optional and with type `undefined` (the `& Partial<Record<Exclude<Operator, T>, undefined>>` part)

Comment: The first one is limpid but you are right I don't want multiple operator. The second one is cryptic and I 'm not sure to understand what's going on

Comment: @brospars added some explanations and changed the second version a bit since the original was not actually forbidding excess properties either

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will enjoy this simplified representation -

```
const rule1 : Expression =
  [ ">", 3, 2 ]

const rule2 : Expression =
  [ "and", [">", 3, 1], ["<", 1, 3] ] 

type Expression = 
  | number
  | string
  | [Operator, Expression, Expression]

type Operator =
  | "var"
  | "==="
  | "!=="
  | "<=" 
  | "<"  
  | ">=" 
  | ">"  
  | "or" 
  | "and"
```

Consider separating `UnaryOp`, `BinaryOp`, `TernaryOp`, etc -

```
const rule1 : Expression =
  [ ">", 3, 2 ]

const rule2 : Expression =
  [ "and", [">", 3, 1], ["<", 1, 3] ] 

const rule3 : Expression =
  [ "?:", [">", 3, 2], ["+", 10, 20], ["not", true]]

type Expression = 
  | number
  | string
  | boolean
  | [UnaryOp, Expression]
  | [BinaryOp, Expression, Expression]
  | [TernaryOp, Expression, Expression, Expression]

type UnaryOp =
  | "not"

type BinaryOp =
  | "var"
  | "==="
  | "!=="
  | "<=" 
  | "<"  
  | ">=" 
  | ">"  
  | "or" 
  | "and"
  | "+"
  | "-"

type TernaryOp =
  | "?:"
```